# UItableView not reloading data swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, reloaddata

```
class MyOrdersViewController:UITableViewController,GMSMapViewDelegate{


private var username = KeychainWrapper.standard.string(forKey: "username")


var googleStaticImages = [UIImage]()



var OrdersByCutomer = [Booking]()

var orderByCustomer: Booking! = Booking()

var driverPhotoUrlString: String!



var driverPhotoURL = [String]()


var refreshCtrl: UIRefreshControl!
```

This view controller is one of the several view controllers embedded in a UItabViewController. When the tab for this viewController is selected for the first time everything works fine, the data source is updating from the getOrdersByCustomer() and all the order cells are displayed. 
But when an order is placed from another view controller(another tab) and I navigate back to this view controller by using self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 2, I am getting the JSON for the new order which was placed from other view controller but the cell for this new order is not showing up.

when the following method is called from viewWillAppear the datasource is updating but the self.tableView.reloadData() doesn't seem to be working and the cell for the newly placed order doesn't show up.

```
func getOrdersByCustomer(){

    if self.refreshCtrl.isRefreshing{

        self.refreshCtrl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Refresh orders..")

    }

    ARSLineProgress.ars_showOnView(self.view)


    Alamofire.request("http://www.*******************************************************ordersbyUser.php?", method: .get, parameters: ["username":username!], encoding: URLEncoding.default).responseString { response in
        print(response.request ?? "")  // original URL request
        print(response.response ?? "") // URL response
        print(response.data!)     // server data
        print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

        if let JSON = response.result.value {
            print("Get Orders By User JSON: " , JSON)


            var jsonObject: [AnyObject]!


            do{
                jsonObject = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: response.data!, options:JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as? Array



                print(jsonObject)

                if jsonObject.isEmpty{

                    ARSLineProgress.hideWithCompletionBlock {

                        self.showAlertWithMessage(message: "No orders found.Use the Book Now tab to order!", ControllerTitle: "My Orders", ActionTitle: "OK")

                        if self.refreshCtrl.isRefreshing{
                            self.refreshCtrl.endRefreshing()
                        }


                    }

                }


            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error)

            }

            var jsonElement: [String:AnyObject]


            for i in 0 ..< jsonObject.count
            {


                jsonElement = jsonObject[i] as! Dictionary





                let staticUrl = jsonElement["staticurl"] as? String

                let orderID = jsonElement["orderid"] as? String
                let customerPrice = jsonElement["userprice"] as? String
                let orderTime = jsonElement["order_time"] as? String
                let orderStatus = jsonElement["stat"] as? String

                let pickUpLatitude = jsonElement["plat"] as? String

                let pickUpLongitude = jsonElement["plon"] as? String
                let dropOffLatitude = jsonElement["dlat"] as? String

                let dropOffLongitude = jsonElement["dlon"] as? String

                let driverphotoURL = jsonElement["driver_photo"] as? String

                print(jsonElement)



                let booking = Booking()

                booking.orderId = orderID!
                booking.price = "₹" + customerPrice!
                booking.pickUpTime = orderTime!
                booking.status = orderStatus!
                booking.pickUpLatitude = pickUpLatitude!
                booking.pickUpLongitude = pickUpLongitude!
                booking.dropOffLatitude = dropOffLatitude!
                booking.dropOffLongitude = dropOffLongitude!
                booking.staticUrl = staticUrl!

                DispatchQueue.main.async{


                    self.OrdersByCutomer.append(booking)

                    if driverphotoURL != nil {

                    self.driverPhotoURL.append(driverphotoURL!)

                        self.refreshTable()

                    }


                }

            }

            if self.refreshCtrl.isRefreshing{
                self.refreshCtrl.endRefreshing()
                self.refreshCtrl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh orders")
            }

            ARSLineProgress.hide()


        }
    }

        }


func refreshTable(){

    DispatchQueue.main.async {

        self.tableView.reloadData()

    }


}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

 return 1
}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return OrdersByCutomer.count


}


override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    print("CELL FOR ROW AT INDEX EXCECUTED")

    self.orderByCustomer = self.OrdersByCutomer[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row] 

    self.driverPhotoUrlString = self.driverPhotoURL[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row]

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MyOrdersCell", for: indexPath) as! MyOrdersCell


    cell.contentView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor

    cell.contentView.layer.borderWidth = 10


    let staticMapsURL = URL(string:orderByCustomer.staticUrl)

    let p = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "39", ofType: "gif")!
    let data = try! Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: p))

    cell.googleStaticMapImageView.kf.indicatorType = .image(imageData: data)

    cell.googleStaticMapImageView.kf.setImage(with: staticMapsURL)

    // if driver photo is not available use default image

    if driverPhotoUrlString.contains("600x300"){

        cell.driverProfileImage.image = UIImage.init(named: "DriverImage.png")

        cell.driverProfileImage.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray

    }else{


    let driverPhotoURL = URL(string: driverPhotoUrlString)

       cell.driverProfileImage.kf.setImage(with: driverPhotoURL)

    cell.driverProfileImage.kf.indicatorType = .activity

    }

    // make the driver profile picture cicular

    cell.driverProfileImage.layer.borderWidth = 1
    cell.driverProfileImage.layer.masksToBounds = false
    cell.driverProfileImage.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    cell.driverProfileImage.layer.cornerRadius = cell.driverProfileImage.frame.height/2
    cell.driverProfileImage.clipsToBounds = true



    cell.orderIdLabel.text = orderByCustomer.orderId

    cell.orderTimeLabel.text = orderByCustomer.pickUpTime


    cell.userPriceLabel.text = orderByCustomer.price

    cell.statusLabel.text = orderByCustomer.status



    return cell



}



override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    super.viewWillAppear(true)

    self.animateTable()

    DispatchQueue.main.async {


    self.getOrdersByCustomer()

    }

   print("ViewWillAppear")




}

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self



    print("ViewDidLoad")


    self.refreshCtrl = UIRefreshControl()
    self.refreshCtrl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.getOrdersByCustomer), for: .valueChanged)
    self.refreshCtrl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh orders")
    self.refreshControl = self.refreshCtrl


}
```

Method in another view controller

```
func transactionCompleted(withResponse response : NSDictionary,errorDescription error:NSError) -> Void {
    self.dismiss(animated: true){

        if response.count != 0{

            print(response)
        }

        self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false

    DispatchQueue.main.async {

        self.submitBookingRequest(){(_status,_success) in



             if _status == "yes"{

                self.effectView.removeFromSuperview()

                self.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

                let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Delivery", message: "Delivery order was placed successfull!", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

                let closeAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.cancel) { (alertAction) -> Void in


                    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

                    let bookNowViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController2") as! BookNowViewController



                    self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 2


                    self.navigationController?.setViewControllers([bookNowViewController], animated: false)



                }

                alertController.addAction(closeAction)

                self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)





             }else{

                self.effectView.removeFromSuperview()

                self.showAlertWithMessage(message: "Problem placing the order!Please Contact Customer Care", ControllerTitle: "Order", ActionTitle: "Close")

            }




        }

        }


    }
}
```

}

Comment: Where is the implementation for the delegate and data source?

Comment: Can you make sure self.tableView is the correct table view. If it is you can try opening the app -> add an order -> before you save add a breakpoint to `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int` and see if the function is being called. If it is called then it is an issue with `getOrdersByCustomer()` otherwise you might not be refreshing the correct tableview. It would work the first time because table views automatically refresh when they are first rendered.

Comment: @Alex S Its in viewDidLoad(). Updated the question.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. I meant where is the implementation for those delegate methods.

Comment: @AlexPelletier Just checked it...numberOfRowsInSection is being called and so is cellForRowAtIndexPath. This is UItableViewController and tableview is the default property.

Comment: @AlexS   Didn't include them in the question....updating now

Comment: Can you add a print statement to the number of rows function and see if that number goes up after you add a new order.

Comment: Also you should probably empty the OrdersByCutomer array when you get a new json response. If you are not seeing duplicate orders after before you made that fix it means the getOrdersByCustomer method isn't working and the number of rows function will not be printing a higher number.

Comment: @AlexPelletier The number of rows have doubled after placing the order..

Comment: @AlexPelletier    Ah mate thank you so much!! It is reloading now and the new order cell is showing up. Emptying that array just before JSON serializaion did the trick. I totally missed emptying that array.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: @ShrikantChidgopkar can you explain how you solved the problem? when one of the answers below fixed your problem, then click on the grey checkmark to mark the question as solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has to do with the `getOrdersByCustomer()`. You are calling that method every time the view appears and adding the new records to the `OrdersByCutomer` array. However you are not emptying the array each time so the first time you will see the initial "ten" records then the next time you will see "21" records with your newly added record being at the end.

Answer (score 0):

```
viewDidLoad()
```

will not re-run when you change tabs in a uitabbarcontroller. To see how that works, chuck a print("") into each of the viewDidLoads of your VCs that are displayed in the tabs - run the app and you'll see they all print at the start, not based on when they are displayed on the screen.

You could use NSNotificationCentre or some kind of listener to make this happen. This is a good library to do this, or you could follow the apple docs.

https://github.com/100mango/SwiftNotificationCenter

The general gist of what you need to do though is set up an event emitter on the 'order placed' function, and a listener on your VC that displays the orders.

Comment: The updates are happening in `viewWillAppear` not `viewDidLoad`